# unable to call function in dojo module from another dojo module

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm getting an Object doesn't support property or method error when I try to call a function in a dojo module.  I have a main page and two modules.  I call the first module from the main page and it works, I call the second module from the first and it works, but I get the error when I try to call the first module from the second.  Here is my code:

main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/css/esri.css">

 <script>
     var dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad:true,
    async: true,
    isDebug:true,
    packages: [
     {name: "Scripts", location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/Scripts"},
    ]


};
</script>
  <script> src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/"></script>

    <script>
        require(["Scripts/Mod1", "Scripts/Mod2"],
        function (Mod1, Mod2) {
            Mod1.M1Method("call from main page");//works great
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div>look here you</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Module 1:

```
define(["Scripts/Mod2"],
function (Mod2) {
    return {

        M1Method: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
            Mod2.M2Method("call from Mod1");//works great
        },
        M1Method2: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }

    }

});
```

Module 2:

```
define(["Scripts/Mod1"],
function (Mod1) {
    return {

        M2Method: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
            Mod1.M1Method2("call from Mod2"); //JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'M1Method2'
        }

    }

});
```

How can I make that call from Mod 2 to Mod1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a cyclic dependency. In module 2, use a require statement. Try something like this:

```
define(["require"],
 function (require) {
  return {
   M2Method: function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
    try {
     require(["Scripts/Mod1"], function(Mod1) {
      Mod1.M1Method2("call from Mod2");
     });
    } catch (dohObj) {
     alert('Doh!, this failed. Stupid answer: ' + dohObj.message);
    }
   }
  }
 }
);
```

Your html code has a typo in that you enclosed the 'script' tag too soon when including dojo.js. Should be something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/"></script>
```

You need to fix that file first to properly include dojo and 'require()'.